# Homophone Riddle 11

Tags: riddle, word

Haven't posted one of these in a while

If you are new to the series, look through Homophone Riddles 1-10

```
It can be in the sea
Or it can be what everyone has
If you find it in the ocean
You'll get out the fork and knife
You can't look for what everyone has 
Because you have to think differently
```

Shouldn't be too hard...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is:

> Sole/soul

Because lines 1 and 3/4 hint at

> a fish

And lines 2 and 5/6 at

> a metaphysical concept

Comment: Correct! Wanted to start easy because I haven't made them in a while. +1 :)